# how to convert if-statement in to switch statement. (textbox properties)

Tags: c#, relational-database

I have a question regarding with C# - programming.

I'm working out on how to make my if statement into for loop or Switch.
P.S. The reason I ask this because I don't know how to make a switch statement that conforms with this sample if Statement

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbDivision.Text) &
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEnduser.Text)))
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"select a.*, c.Enduser          
                            from matt.ServiceInfo a
                            left join matt.Divisions b
                            on
                            a.DivisionCode = b.DivisionCode
                            left join matt.EmployeeInfo c
                            on a.DivisionCode = c.DivisionCode
                            where b.DivisionCode like @Division";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Division", cmbDivision.Text + '%');


                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    btnEdit.Visible = true;
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    dgvRptView.DataSource = dt;

            }
```

here's the full snippet

```
public void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var cmdconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString)) 
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = cmdconn;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbDivision.Text) &
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEnduser.Text)))
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"select a.*, c.Enduser          
                            from matt.ServiceInfo a
                            left join matt.Divisions b
                            on
                            a.DivisionCode = b.DivisionCode
                            left join matt.EmployeeInfo c
                            on a.DivisionCode = c.DivisionCode
                            where b.DivisionCode like @Division";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Division", cmbDivision.Text + '%');


                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    btnEdit.Visible = true;
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    dgvRptView.DataSource = dt;

            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEnduser.Text) &
                    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbDivision.Text)))
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"select a.*, c.Enduser          
                            from matt.ServiceInfo a
                            left join matt.Divisions b
                            on
                            a.DivisionCode = b.DivisionCode
                            left join matt.EmployeeInfo c
                            on a.DivisionCode = c.DivisionCode
                            where c.Enduser like @Enduser";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enduser", tbEnduser.Text + '%');

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                dgvRptView.DataSource = dt;

            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEnduser.Text) &
                    (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbDivision.Text)))
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"select a.*
                from matt.ServiceInfo a
                left join matt.Divisions b
                on a.DivisionCode = b.DivisionCode
                where b.DivisionCode like @Division";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enduser", tbEnduser.Text + '%');
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmbDivison", cmbDivision.Text + '%');
                btnEdit.Visible = true;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                dgvRptView.DataSource = dt;

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill the following fields");
            }
        }

    }
```

my Code seems to be working fine, the thing is, i want to enhance my coding,
so I decided to convert it in to for loop to shorten my code. Apparently I'm not familiar with properties of using for each loop. or will it be better if I use Switch case, which is I am not also familiar with. Can someone help me to convert my code in a shorter lines?. Thank you in Advance my brothers/sisters.

Comment: You are confusing `&` and `&&`.

Comment: You don't need a switch or worse a foreach loop, you need to think better at how to refactor your code to set the command text and the parameters for the three situations that you want to handle

Comment: If you use stored procedure instead of the inline query then you dont even need to use if or switch statements. Stored procedure will have where clause as b.DivisionCode like %IsNull(@Division, b.DivisionCode)% and c.Enduser like %ISNULL(@Enduser,c.Enduser)%

Comment: If you still want to go with the switch clause (condition) then your code is repeated only CommandText and parameter are different so you can put those statements only in the logical statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

switch work with compile-time constant values. what you need is to get rid off duplicate code inside if branches

```
public void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEnduser.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbDivision.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill the following fields");
        return;
    }
    using (var cmdconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString)) 
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cmdconn;
        string text = @"select a.*, c.Enduser          
                        from matt.ServiceInfo a
                        left join matt.Divisions b
                        on
                        a.DivisionCode = b.DivisionCode
                        left join matt.EmployeeInfo c
                        on a.DivisionCode = c.DivisionCode";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEnduser.Text) &
                (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbDivision.Text)))
        {
            text += " where b.DivisionCode like @Division and c.Enduser like @Enduser";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enduser", tbEnduser.Text + '%');
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmbDivison", cmbDivision.Text + '%');
            btnEdit.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbDivision.Text) &
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEnduser.Text)))
        {
            text += " where b.DivisionCode like @Division";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Division", cmbDivision.Text + '%');
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEnduser.Text) &
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbDivision.Text)))
        {
            text+=" where c.Enduser like @Enduser";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enduser", tbEnduser.Text + '%');
        }

        cmd.CommandText = text;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        dgvRptView.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

A switch statement needs a single expression which is compared against a list of single Values (enums, ints, strings).

In your case you have three different expressions and nothing to compare against.

Of course you could trick your condition into an int:

```
int conditionInt = 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbDivision.Text) ? 1 : 0
    +
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbDivision.Text) ? 2 : 0
```

and then have the switch cases 0, 1, 2 and 3
but this is definitely **not recommended** and considered *obfuscated code*

Better you concentrate on refactoring your code otherwise:

- avoid duplicated code, put this in a method.
- use parameterized sql

---

**Edit**

Suggestions for overall structure
Instead of

```
if(!empty1 && !empty2)
else if(!empty1 && empty2)
...
```

you coud structure it like this:

```
if(!empty1)
{
    if(!empty2)
    {
    }
    else // empty2
    {
    }
}
else // empty1
{
    if(!empty2)
    {
    }
    else // empty2
    {
    }
}
```

To make it *clearer* and/or more readable, but I consider this change more a matter of taste: Look at it and decide for yourself what makes you more happy if you read it after 4 weeks

Comment: so does it mean its better to stay in that format? am i on a right track on getting my system done.? (excluding my spaghetti code format)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think switch will be best option in your case. You would have to convert the if statements to some type which can be used in switch statement, eg. enum, number. It seems that your SQL statement is pretty the same, can't you stick with 2 params query and just pass inside the empty string if is empty?

Answer (score 1):

`switch` statements are only used when testing for various values of a expression.  This is not appropriate in your case because you multiple expressions to test; so `if` is the correct style.

However, I would just do the SQL command creation and parameter binding in the `if` statements.  Place the `SqlDataApator` after all the `if` statements.

**Update**

ASh has demonstrated what I said.  Please vote for him/her.

Answer (score 1):

`switch` statement is not really a better alternative here. But you can refactor the way you build the sql command:

```
var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString);
using (var cmdconn = new SqlConnection(connStr)) 
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = cmdconn;
    var conditions = new List<string>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbDivision.Text))
    {
        conditions.Add("b.DivisionCode like @Division");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Division", cmbDivision.Text + '%');
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEnduser.Text))
    {
        conditions.Add("c.Enduser like @Enduser");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enduser", tbEnduser.Text + '%');
    }

    var sql = @"select a.*, c.Enduser          
              from matt.ServiceInfo a
              left join matt.Divisions b on a.DivisionCode = b.DivisionCode
              left join matt.EmployeeInfo c on a.DivisionCode = c.DivisionCode
              where " + string.Join(" and ", conditions);

    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    btnEdit.Visible = true;
    da.Fill(dt);
    dgvRptView.DataSource = dt;
}
```